# How to test speed of javascript code - SVG vs CANVAS

Tags: html, performance, testing, canvas, svg

I have two similar examples but one using SVG other using CANVAS:

WIth html5 canvas: http://jsbin.com/yepigu/5
With SVG: http://jsbin.com/yumova

I need to know which render is faster. What I need to use in my case?
Is there some online tool for that or I need to make some timer into code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perf test the 2 alternatives, run each alternative while recording starting & ending times.

BTW, I reworked your canvas stroked line to work without shadowing which should speed that up:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var pts = [{x:22,y:59.45},{x:136,y:66},{x:170,y:99},{x:171,y:114},{x:183,y:125},{x:218,y:144},{x:218,y:165},{x:226,y:193},{x:254,y:195},{x:283,y:195},{x:292,y:202},{x:325,y:213},{x:341,y:134},{x:397,y:245},{x:417,y:548}];


ctx.lineCap='round';
ctx.lineJoin='round';
ctx.lineWidth=25;
ctx.strokeStyle='red';
drawPolyline(pts);
ctx.lineWidth=22;
ctx.strokeStyle='pink';
drawPolyline(pts);
ctx.lineWidth=2;
ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
drawPolyline(pts);

function drawPolyline(pts){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(pts[0].x,pts[0].y);
  for(var i=1;i<pts.length;i++){
    ctx.lineTo(pts[i].x,pts[i].y);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=600></canvas>
```

Comment: This mostly measures parsing as rendering is asynchronous. There's no way to measure exactly what is asked for unless the UA provides internal tools to do so or you load some kind of plugin with privileged access. It would be a privacy hole if there were.

Comment: Good point--my bad. I'll edit to suggest simple elapsed time tests instead. Thanks for having my back :-)